# jQuery - Several select menu options make a field show/hide

Tags: jquery, select

I tried looking for posts like this one but although many are similar, none address my problem properly.

Here's my situation:

I have two select menus, **Country** and **State**, one of top of the other. Their default values are "-Select-".

If the user selects another country different than *United States* or *Canada*, the **State** select menu should hide and a regular text field should show (see HTML structure below). If, after selecting *United States* or *Canada* the user decides to select any other country, then the text box that just appeared should hide again and the select menu for **State** should reappear.

Last, if the user selects *United States* or *Canada* at first, nothing happens, the **State** select stays visible.

Any help you can give me with this, it's greatly appreciated.

**

This is the basic HTML for this:

***Country's* select:**

```
<select name="country">
 <option value="null" selected="selected">&mdash;Select&mdash;</option>
 <option value="United States">United States</option>
 <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
 <option value="null" >-----------------------------------------</option>
 <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
 <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
 ...
</select>
```

***State's* select & *input*:**

```
<select name="state">
 <option value="null" selected="selected">&mdash;Select&mdash;</option>
 <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
 <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
 ...
</select>

 <br>

<input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" class="country-textbox">
```

**UPDATE 6/14:** sAc's solution worked perfectly. However, I just thought of something else:

I also decided to include another select menu for the Canadian Provinces (doh!), so now:

1. When *Canada* is selected, the **United States** select and the text field should be hidden, and the **Canada** select should be visible.
2. When *United States* is selected, the **Canada** select and the text field should be hidden, and the **United States** select should be visible.
3. If any other value is selected, the **United States** and **Canada** selects should be hidden and the text field visible.

Thanks a million for your help.

**UPDATE 6/15:** Well, no additional help for the extended version. Thanks anyway everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
$('select[name="country"]').change(function(){
  if ($(this).val() === "United States" || $(this).val() === "Canada")
  {
    $('select[name="state"]').show();
  }
  else
  {
    $('select[name="state"]').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Yup, same thing. You're quick.

Comment: Your solution worked great! Thanks sAc.

However, I added a new functionality I need help with. I messed around with your code but honestly I couldn't decipher how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery!

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#textfield").hide();
    $("select[name=country]").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'United States' || $(this).val() == 'Canada'){
            $("#textfield").show();
            $("select[name=state]").hide();
        } else {
            $("#textfield").hide();
            $("select[name=state]").show();
        }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('select[name="country"]').change( function(){
        var thisval = $(this).val();
        if( thisval !== 'United States' && thisval !== 'Canada' ) {
             $('select[name="state"]').hide();
             $('#textfield').show();
        } else {
             $('select[name="state"]').show();
             $('#textfield').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

AND

```
$('select[name="country"]').change(function(){
  if ($(this).val() === "United States" || $(this).val() === "Canada")
  {
    $('select[name="state"]').show();
    $('input[name="text-field"]').hide();
  }
  else
  {
    $('select[name="state"]').hide();
    $('input[name="text-field"]').show();
  }
});
```